# What is the best way to return a stack variable from a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a situation where I need to return the first item found in a list, How do I return it when I use recursion ?:

```
def get_hostname (ifname):
    try :
        # Do something to get hostname
        return hostname
    except IOError:
        return -1


def get_hostname_r(lst):
    if not lst:
        return False
    if get_hostname(lst[0]) != -1 :
        print 'Found ', get_hostname(lst[0])
        return get_hostname(lst[0]) # DOESNT WORK
    else :
        print 'Not found ', get_hostname(lst[0])
        get_hostname_r(lst[1:])

print 'return = ', get_hostname_r(['eth1','eth2','eth3','eth4','eth5' ])
```

I understand that the return goes back to the calling stack but Iam looking here for the best practices without using a global variable to get the value?

Comment: You're missing the `return` keyword for the `else` case: `return get_hostname_r(lst[1:])`. Also, it's good design to have the values returned by a single function all be the same type; use exceptions to indicate errors and, well, exceptional results.

Comment: Extract `get_hostname(lst[0])` into a variable so that it only gets called once. This won't solve your problem, it's just bothering me because it's inefficient. Also this is not really a good use case for recursion, I would recommend just doing this with a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return the value, the returned value is handed over the whole recursion stack:

```
def get_hostname_r(lst):
    if not lst:
        return False
    if get_hostname(lst[0]) != -1 :
        print 'Found ', get_hostname(lst[0])
        return get_hostname(lst[0])
    else:
        print 'Not found ', get_hostname(lst[0])
        return get_hostname_r(lst[1:])
```

But easier to read is a for-loop:

```
def get_hostname_r(interfaces):
    for interface in interfaces:
        result = get_hostname(interface)
        if result != -1:
            return result
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you can't do anything about the IO error, don't mask it by returning -1 ("What does -1 mean? Why didn't I get a host name back?"). Just document that `get_hostname` might raise an IOError.

```
def get_hostname(ifname):
    # Do stuff that might raise an IOError
    return hostname
```

The same goes for the recursive version. Either return a valid hostname, or raise an exception (or let an uncaught exception continue).

```
def get_hostname_r(lst):
    if not lst:
        raise IOError("Hostname not found")

    try:
        hostname = get_hostname(lst[0])
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Found {0}'.format(hostname)
        return hostname
    except IOError:
        print 'Not found with {0}'.format(lst[0])
        return get_hostname_r(lst[1:])
```

Of course, recursion isn't really the best way to write this; use a simple `for` loop instead to iterate over `lst`.

```
def get_hostname_iter(lst):
    for ifname in lst:
        try:
            return get_hostname(ifname)
        except IOError:
            continue
    raise IOError("Hostname not found")
```